# Oracle import dmp file: ora exceptions

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, rac

I'm trying to import a `.dmp` file to my oracle RAC database using the following command:

```
C:\app\ptmp>impdp [user]/[password]@'DEVRAC-SCAN:1521/DB' DUMPFILE=UPG_E_7d291ff.dmp
 LOGFILE=UPG_E_7d291ff.log TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE
```

And I get the following output from oracle:

```
Import: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Thu Dec 17 09:43:13 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit
Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management,
OLAP,
Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```

I've looked around a little bit and some people (https://community.oracle.com/thread/3788748?start=0&tstart=0 && https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878631/expdp-from-oracle-rac-environment) have said it could be a permissions thing so I checked permissions with:

```
C:\app\ptmp>icacls c:\app\oracle\admin\pldb\dpdump
c:\app\oracle\admin\pldb\dpdump Everyone:(R,W)
                                BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
                                NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
                                PL\PLORACLE:(OI)(CI)(F)
                                DEVRAC1\Administrator:(OI)(CI)(F)
                                DEVRAC1\ORA_GRID_LISTENERS:(OI)(CI)(F)
                                BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                                NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                                PL\PLORACLE:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                                DEVRAC1\Administrator:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                                DEVRAC1\ORA_GRID_LISTENERS:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
```

the oracle `tnslistener` runs under `PL\PLORACLE` user. <-- this is actually not true, see edits.

I used these commands to create/change the data pump directory:

```
echo create or replace directory DATA_PUMP_DIR as 'C:\app\oralce\admin\pldb\dpdump\'; >1_UPDATE_DUMP_LOC.SQL
echo grant read,write on directory DATA_PUMP_DIR to public; >>1_UPDATE_DUMP_LOC.SQL
```

They were ran using this command in a batch file:

```
sqlplus -S [user]/[password]@'DEVRAC-SCAN:1521/PLDB' <1_UPDATE_DUMP_LOC.SQL >1_UPDATE_DUMP_LOC.LST
```

The user that is running the commands has `sysdba` privileges for the database. So, with all this, I can't really understand why the import of the `.dmp` file isn't working.

**EDIT:**

The oracle `tnslistener` is actually running as `local service` rather than `PL\PLORACLE` as I thought. The `OracleJobSchedulePLDB_1`, `OracleServicePLDB_1` and `OracleVssWriterPLDB_1` run under `PL\PLORACLE` though. The rest of the oracle services run as `Local System/Service`

Comment: Have you tried elevating your command prompt?  As in, right click on the Command Prompt Icon => Run as Administrator, then run impdp.

Comment: @KrisJohnston I had tried that, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path I had been tryig `c:\app\oracle\admin\pldb\dpdump` seemed to be locked down by Oracle so I just instead went with `c:\app\ptmp` and everything seemed to work just fine for me...not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's the write to the directory that's failing, but at the OS level.

Does the OS user runing impdp have OS permissions to write to the directory?

Comment: Should, I was logged in as `DEVRAC1\Administrator` while running the commands.

Comment: It does not matter. User "ploracle" must have write permission.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Would these two entries from `icacls` (`PL\PLORACLE:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)` and `PL\PLORACLE:(OI)(CI)(F)`) not indicate full permissions for the folder location?